# Nest js failed to execute command: with 'node'

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to init my first NestJS project but met this fail:

```
-----------------------------------------
$ nest new testproj
⚡  We will scaffold your app in a few seconds..

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Failed to execute command: node @nestjs/schematics:application --name=testproj --directory=undefined --no-dry-run --no-skip-git --no-strict --package-manager=undefined --language="ts" --collection="@nestjs/schematics"
------------------------------------------

Tryed to reinstall NodeJS, but no luck. 

$ node -v
v16.13.1

$ nest -v
8.1.6

$ npm -v
8.3.0
```

Any help will be appreciated.

[image: System variables set like that]

Comment: That was my first action - didn't work...

Comment: Yep, the path is set, but not with variable, like that -> C:\Program Files\nodejs

Comment: Sorry for mixing up. I mean at some discussions people advice to set variables like SET PATH=%NODEJS%;%PATH%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240347/discussion-between-cherrydt-and-olekskop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

If your `PATH` somewhere has a *file* in it and not a folder (can also be in the middle of a path, with some `\other\stuff` appended like `C:\stuff\somefile.txt\stuff`), then this can happen due to an error when Git bash is translating `PATH` before calling `cmd.exe`, resulting in part of the `PATH` not being forwarded and making binaries in that part "not found".

---

**Details:**

After some investigation via chat, it turned out that the root cause was a bad `GRADLE_HOME` environment variable.

<sub>Yes, Gradle has nothing to do with node.js or nest, but bear with me, this is one of those moments where a TV episode starts with a totally crazy scene and you wonder what the heck happened that led to this, and then you get "6 hours earlier..."</sub>

---

So, Git bash obviously succeeded in finding node, because it ran the `nest` CLI (which is a node script). But then, somehow, cmd (which is called by node when executing shell commands) did *not* find node. This normally should not happen.

Tracing the events with Process Monitor revealed that bash (`sh.exe`) passed a truncated `PATH` variable to `node.exe`. It just ended abruptly somewhere in the middle, and `C:\Program Files\nodejs` (which was towards the end of it) was not passed along.

The reason for this turned out to be an entry in the `PATH` that looked like this: `C:\foobar\file.zip\bin`. The transition *into* bash worked, as the full path (including this bad entry as `/c/foobar/file.zip/bin`) could be seen in bash's `$PATH`, and `/c/Program Files/nodejs` was there too.

But the transition *from* bash to `node.exe` failed. In the process of converting the Linux-style paths to Windows-style paths before passing the variable on to `node.exe`, bash silently failed in the middle of the string and stopped processing it - as soon as this `/c/foobar/file.zip/bin` entry was encountered. `C:\foobar\file.zip` did exist, and it turns out Git bash behaves like this when it unexpectedly encounters a "not a directory" error from the OS when querying the path segment ("file not found" is fine) - as a result of attempting to access *a "subdirectory" of a file*. Removing this entry from the `PATH` made everything work normally.

The source of this entry was actually `%GRADLE_PATH%\bin` in the Windows `PATH`, and the reason this caused the problem was that `GRADLE_PATH` itself was incorrectly set to a file (`C:\foobar\file.zip`) instead of a directory.

---

There are three ways to resolve this:

1. Remove `%GRADLE_PATH%\bin` from the `PATH`.
2. Fix `GRADLE_PATH` to point to a directory.
3. Delete or rename the `C:\foobar\file.zip` file.